# Determining Bundler in Angular 2 Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, systemjs

I am working on a angular 2 project. I am new to this, so I need to determine the bundler that is being used(System.js or Webpack, etc).

How should I determine that?

I use ng build to build my project, which creates the dist folder with js files in it. 
Is there a specific bundler being used or angular-cli is the one creating the bundles. I am confused. Please help

Comment: angular cli uses webpack

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Cli uses Webpack
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

check commit message on plugins folder:
"feat(@angular/cli): use same webpack config for karma"